# All photos are gone after updating my iPhone to iOS 5

Tags: iphone, windows, upgrade, ios

After installation of iOS 5, once it was done restoring my settings, apps, etc I got an error message -19. All apps restored successfully. But I don't see the photos. I tried to revert to iOS 4.3.3 again but I got stuck again with error -10.

At this point, I just want my photos back. After that I can update the iPhone to the latest version. Is there a way to restore the photos from the iPhone's file system? I tried accessing the phone's contents using Ubuntu, there I got error message 15.

Comment: Did you already have a look at the instructions in http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3694? Can you still access your phone directly or does it just show the "Connect to iTunes" screen?

Comment: I couldn't find 10.

19 is basically an unknown error! I tried the solution which was eject-connect again-update. But it didn't work.

Comment: BTW, The phone is perfectly fine. I just lost my photos.

Comment: So, the phone works but your photos are gone? Do you have a recent backup in iTunes and did you sync your photos at all?

Comment: Unfortunately no! I don't have them on my PC. I was just relying on the backup the iTunes does before the update. That backup took very long so I slept and in the morning I saw that I don't have the photos anymore :(

Comment: somebody please help me!

Comment: Are you saying that you're sure that iTunes did not back up the photos in the long backup overnight? In the morning, did you stop the backup in progress or had it finished? If it had finished iTunes should have the photos.

Comment: When I woke up, I found out that the PC is restarted for some unknown reason :( I opened iTunes and continued the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766), iTunes should automatically backup your photos and videos:

> Backed-up information includes purchased music, TV shows, apps, and books*; **photos and video in the Camera Roll**; ...

However, the format of the backup doesn't make it easy to access those photos. Therefore, you can use a program such as [iPhone Backup Extractor](http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/) which should make it a lot easier to recover data from the backup, including photos. I haven't tried the app, so I can't personally recommend it, but it did get good reviews on [CNET](http://download.cnet.com/iPhone-Backup-Extractor/3000-18553_4-75373326.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for previous backup data in iTunes folders:

> your user folder > Library > Application Support > MobileSync > Backup